# Sub-matrices with a real spectrum

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, schrodinger-operators

This question arises from the study of PT-symmetric quantum mechanics.

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ complex-valued matrix with a real spectrum.

If $A$ is Hermitian, then any sub-matrix corresponding to to the
Cartesian product $I \times I$, where $I \subseteq [n]$ is also Hermitian
and hence has a real spectrum.

But what if $A$ is a non-Hermitian matrix (but with a real spectrum)?
Under what conditions do all principal sub-matrices of $A$ also have a real spectrum? 
[edited following the first two comments.]

Comment: There's no such $\ell$, for example $\begin{pmatrix} i & 1\\ 1 & -i\end{pmatrix}$ has real spectrum (equal to $0$), but there are $1\times 1$ submatrices with complex spectrum.

Comment: To extend the above, it doesn't help to try larger $n$, as we can just add in diagonal 1s, and any $n - 1$ sub matrix using only one part of the 2 by 2 above will have nonreal spectrum.